# Should questions about pronunciation of a word be closed as "general reference"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I don't think they should be closed, but considering that it could be enough to look the pronunciation reported in a dictionary, should questions about pronunciation be closed using the "general reference" reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is "How do you pronounce this?", which is a Poll, then I think so.

But not if the questions are like:

- What is the *correct* pronunciation of **x**?
- I've heard two different pronunciations, **x** and **y**, what is the correct one?
- What are the differences between the BrE pronunciation and the AmE one for **x**?
- Are there differences in meaning if I use the alternative pronunciation for **x**?
- What is the origin of the pronunciation of **x**?

Just the first ones that came to my mind, in the end, it's always a matter of "being specific".

I'm not sure about "What is the pronunciation for **x**?", because I've seen it left open before, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: The reason they have been left open before is that the closing reason "general reference" was not yet implemented. The description of that closing reason is: "This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information."

Comment: @Kiamlaluno: Ah ok, then I guess they should be closed as well.