# Question is on hold - should it be? What is considered a "general reference"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, general-reference, pronunciation

My question is put on hold for being off-topic: [How do I pronounce the name "Aurelius"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206495/how-do-i-pronounce-the-name-aurelius)

Since I wasn't exactly sure what the "general reference" reason actually is (*When looking at the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) my question would appear to be on-topic.*) I was looking it up a bit here on Meta.

Finding [this answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1023/60910) I would think my question is asked in the correct format.

I also found [this question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/939/how-to-respond-to-dictionary-general-reference-questions) which says:

> **general reference**: this question is too basic; the answer is indexed in any number of general internet reference sources designed specifically to find that type of information.

And there is another [discussion](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/google-is-not-general-reference) here talking about how Google should not be considered a general reference.

Also, a quote from one of the comments on my question:

> @phenry: ...and I just looked up "Aurelius" in three different online references and found no pronunciation advice, so it's not "general reference" either.

Is my question off-topic? Also, there seems to be a lot of conflicting information on what the `General Reference` close reason should actually be used for - What is the current viewpoint on this?

Comment: Also relevant: [What General Reference answers this question?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3119/what-general-reference-answers-this-question)

Comment: This question has been reopened.